# reuse of same object of chart in highcharts to minimize coding

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular7

I am creating a dashboard and atleats 10 PIE charts are displayed on the page. Each PIE chart is different by some values only and remaining ALL other things are same.

Angular 7 + HighCharts I am using. Below is the code. If I try to use `chart2` 2 times in HTML, it appears only once. If I use a different variable for same code copy pasted, it works good.

1. How can I minimize code or reuse the same `chart` object by passing different values?
2. In the constructor `let` keyword is needed and outside constructor it works without using it
3. for 10 different PIE charts, all are differed by only `series` in the chart object. How one object can be used for all 10?.

   ```
   @ Component({
    selector: 'app-chart',
    templateUrl: './chart.Component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./chart.Component.css'],
    providers: [LotoService],
   })

   export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

       let chart8: any;
       let chart2: any;

   }

   CP_A2A = 10;
   CP_A2CA = 10;

   ngOnInit() {}

   chart2 = new Chart({
           chart: {
               plotBackgroundColor: null,
               plotBorderWidth: null,
               plotShadow: false,
               type: 'pie',
               backgroundColor: '#fff',
               marginTop: 20,
               height: 300
           },
           credits: {
               enabled: false
           },
           title: {
               text: null,
               style: {
                   color: '#858585',
                   fontSize: '14px'
               }
           },
           tooltip: {
               pointFormat: '{point.y}'
           },
           series: [{
                   type: 'pie',
                   name: 'Share',
                   data: [{
                           name: 'Approved',
                           y: 500
                       }, {
                           name: 'Conditionally Approved',
                           y: 300
                       }, {
                           name: 'Not Approved',
                           y: 200
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ],
           plotOptions: {
               pie: {
                   allowPointSelect: true,
                   cursor: 'pointer',
                   dataLabels: {
                       enabled: false
                   },
                   showInLegend: false,
                   colors: ['#00366E', '#3693F8', '#C8E7FB'],
                   center: ['50%', '37%']
               }
           },
       });
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Fix will be

You can actually keep the configuration in a default config variable, as below

```
defaultChartConfig = {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie',
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            marginTop: 20,
            height: 300
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: null,
            style: {
                color: '#858585',
                fontSize: '14px'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.y}'
        },
        series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Share',
                data: [ ]
            }
        ],
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: false,
                colors: ['#00366E', '#3693F8', '#C8E7FB'],
                center: ['50%', '37%']
            }
        },
    }
```

then `forEach` chart you should reuse the config and change the data as below

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     const chart = new Chart(this. defaultChartConfig);
     chart.series.data = ____/// whatever data
     this.charts.push(chart)
}
```

use `ngFor` in the UI for displaying the charts

**Better approach** will be create a generic `pie-chart` component with a selector `app-pie-chart` using the highcharts and accept the series object as `Input()` from a parent component use this new chart with it's selector